# Nodes displaying random property instead of the first property 'name'

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I am working with some email data in neo4j(Neo4j Browser version: 3.2.20/Neo4j Server version: 3.5.8 (community)) and on import I would like the `name` to be displayed on the node but the `subPlusDomain` is displayed on the node.

This is my import:

```
call apoc.load.json("file:///sessions/sender_test.json") yield value unwind value.sender as sender
create (s:Sender { name:sender.name, domain:sender.domain, subPlusDomain:sender.subPlusDomain, to:sender.to, url:sender.url })
```

I have also tried the following but am running into the same issue:

```
call apoc.load.json("file:///sessions/sender_test.json") yield value unwind value.sender as sender
MERGE (s:Sender {name:sender.name})
    ON CREATE SET s.name = sender.name, s.domain = sender.domain, s.subPlusDomain = sender.subPlusDomain, s.to = sender.to, s.url = sender.url
```

Note: all of the `names` are unique and all of the `subPlusDomain` are different but when you view the nodes there are 6 of them displaying the same `subPlusDomain` name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The visualizer is separate from the database. At present there is no way to set anything in the database to tell the visualizer application which property should be used for display caption.

You can of course change the caption used per node label in the visualizer itself. On the line just below the query in the visualizer pane you should see node labels. Click on one and at the bottom of the visualizer pane you should see display options that will affect all nodes with that label, including the size and color to use for the nodes and which property to use as the caption.